# why doesn't setInterval get called until loop is over

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, setinterval

In my game loop, I want to ask three questions. After that a setInterval should be called which works with the answers to those three questions. After this Interval is finished, I want to repeat this process 3 more times. However, when the loop starts, It goes through the questions 3 times and *then* does the setInterval part.

Edit: rewrote everything in English.

```js
//require "prompt-sync"
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });

//Auto class
class Car{
    constructor(brand, speed, maxSpeed, currentSpeed){
        this.carBrand = brand;
        this.carSpeed = speed;
        this.carMaxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        this.carCurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
    }

    drive(){
        if(this.carCurrentSpeed >= this.carMaxSpeed){
            clearInterval(inter);
            console.log("too fast");
        }else{
            this.carCurrentSpeed = this.carCurrentSpeed + this.carSpeed;
            console.log(this.carBrand + " has a speed of " + this.currentSpeed + " km/h");
        }
    }    
}


//gameloop
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    //infos from usr
    let brand = prompt("what brand is your car? ");
    let speed = parseInt(prompt("How much speed does your car gain per second? "));
    let maxSpeed = parseInt(prompt("what is the maximum speed of your car? "));
    
    //create Object
    var usrAuto = new Car(brand, speed, maxSpeed, 0);

    //setInterval
    var inter = setInterval(usrAuto.plus.bind(usrAuto), 1000);
```

Comment: To be sure I understand. You want to execute the code in the loop, wait, and then re-run it?

Comment: I don't know if I would call it "waiting". I just want to re-run when the serInterval is finished. Isn't it normal that a for loop doesn't start again until every statement is finished?

Comment: Ok now with full code I think I get it better. Let me edit the answer

Comment: I looked again and saw the issue here. You expect the code to run the interval and, once done, continue the code where it left. It doesn't work because setInterval doesn't stop the code, it makes an asynchronous task, that will run on the delays.

Comment: that solves my problem completely. Thanks for taking the time to look through all my code. I understand your solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer:
You expect the code to run the interval and, once done, continue the code where it left. It doesn't work because setInterval doesn't stop the code, it makes an asynchronous task, that will run on each delay set.

What you can do is just a simple while loop and "sleep" for 1 second. As sleep doesn't exist on JavasScript, there are some ways to make a new one, here is one ofthe simplest ways.

```
 const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

//Auto class
class Car{
    constructor(brand, speed, maxSpeed, currentSpeed){
        this.carBrand = brand;
        this.carSpeed = speed;
        this.carMaxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        this.carCurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
        this.crashed = false;
    }
    drive(){
        if(this.carCurrentSpeed >= this.carMaxSpeed){
            console.log("too fast");
            this.crashed= true;
        }else{
            this.carCurrentSpeed = this.carCurrentSpeed + this.carSpeed;
            console.log(this.carBrand + " has a speed of " + this.carCurrentSpeed + " km/h");
        }
    }    
}

var cars = []
//gameloop
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    //infos from usr
    let brand = prompt("what brand is your car? ");
    let speed = parseInt(prompt("How much speed does your car gain per second? "));
    let maxSpeed = parseInt(prompt("what is the maximum speed of your car? "));
    
    //create Object
    var usrAuto = new Car(brand, speed, maxSpeed, 0);
    while (usrAuto.crashed == false){
        usrAuto.drive()
        sleep(1000)
    }

}
```

Comment: urgh. I thought that this would help me. but It didn't. I still don't understand what I did wrong and don't understand your proposal. sry.
What I'm programming is kind of a racing game (in the most simplest way). the user says the name of his car, how much speed the car gains per sec and what the maximum speed for his car is. Now, I want to compere 3 cars. after the first "raced", the second should start.
does that help in any way? Or do you think you could help me if I posted all of my code?

Comment: Ok I’m going to edit to try and make it clearer. And yes, your whole code would make it clearer.

Comment: I added my whole code to the question. Most things are written in German. If anything is unclear, a translator might help. or ask me

Comment: I rewrote everything to English. Maybe It's now easier to read. Sorry for posting shitty code. 
Thanks for the patience @Clement Genninasca